# yolov7 extremely low precision

Tags: yolo, yolov7

I am training yolov7 on the [mask detection dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/andrewmvd/face-mask-detection). However, after 50 epoch, the result is extremely unsatisfying.
[image: image output by detect.py]

This is the command I used to train the model. I tried to train with `--weights yolov7-e6e.pt` and `--weights ''`.

```
python train.py --weights yolov7-e6e.pt --data data/masks.yaml --workers 1 --batch-size 4 --img 416 --cfg cfg/training/yolov7-masks.yaml --name yolov7 --epochs 50
```

The graph of the result of the training process with yolov7-e6e.pt weights.
[image: yolov7-e6e.pt result]
This is the output of the training process with yolov7-e6e.pt weights.

```
0/49     1.38G   0.07534   0.01625   0.01766    0.1093        38       416  0.001874  0.002353 1.415e-05 2.142e-06   0.09831   0.05273   0.04727
      1/49     1.33G     0.076   0.01668   0.01298    0.1057        13       416 0.0007152   0.02824 2.541e-05 2.596e-06    0.1006   0.02764   0.08517
      2/49     1.33G   0.07455   0.01629  0.009562    0.1004        38       416  0.002424   0.08941 0.0002667 4.326e-05     0.103   0.02545    0.1883
      3/49     1.33G   0.07039   0.01604  0.007317   0.09376        40       416 0.0005907   0.03529 2.676e-05  3.21e-06   0.08233   0.03562  0.007157
      4/49     1.33G   0.06965   0.01664  0.005538   0.09183        40       416 0.0008659   0.01412 3.977e-05 6.659e-06   0.09394    0.0305    0.2415
      5/49     1.33G   0.06451   0.01585  0.004107   0.08446        21       416  0.001491   0.08941 0.0001422 1.695e-05   0.08565   0.05161    0.1683
      6/49     1.33G   0.06187   0.01533  0.003019   0.08021        38       416 0.0007804   0.04471 3.915e-05 5.694e-06   0.09762   0.02665    0.2599
      7/49     1.33G   0.06325   0.01531    0.0024   0.08096        50       416 0.0007543  0.007059 2.788e-05 4.372e-06   0.08728   0.03365   0.04053
      8/49     1.33G   0.06225   0.01533   0.00185   0.07943        41       416  0.001059   0.06353 7.521e-05 1.034e-05   0.08493   0.03549   0.06227
      9/49     1.33G   0.06357   0.01504  0.001343   0.07996        20       416 0.0007462   0.04471 3.731e-05 4.299e-06   0.08563   0.05259    0.0783
     10/49     1.33G   0.06214   0.01495 0.0009087     0.078        25       416 0.0007215   0.04235 3.414e-05  5.18e-06   0.08225   0.03767   0.04993
     11/49     1.33G    0.0601   0.01474 0.0007172   0.07556        27       416  0.002088    0.1247  0.000272 3.507e-05   0.08265   0.03781    0.1331
     12/49     1.33G    0.0606   0.01474 0.0007222   0.07606        11       416  0.001964    0.1176 0.0002423 3.417e-05   0.08264   0.04058    0.1563
     13/49     1.33G   0.06062   0.01436 0.0007411   0.07572        65       416 0.0003194   0.01882 9.731e-06 1.367e-06   0.08105   0.03895  0.004329
     14/49     1.33G   0.06156   0.01363 0.0005831   0.07577        14       416 0.0004628  0.009412 5.389e-06 9.552e-07    0.1165    0.2524     4.533
     15/49     1.33G    0.0619   0.01372 0.0005137   0.07614        17       416 0.0004062   0.02353 1.188e-05 1.567e-06   0.09205   0.07114     1.061
     16/49     1.33G    0.0629   0.01427 0.0008267     0.078        18       416 7.851e-05  0.004706 8.282e-07  1.15e-07   0.08322   0.03756 0.0005495
     17/49     1.33G   0.06253   0.01418 0.0006002   0.07731        12       416 0.0003922   0.02353 1.121e-05 1.856e-06   0.08171   0.03805  0.003113
     18/49     1.33G   0.06219   0.01398 0.0004657   0.07663        21       416  0.001262   0.06353 0.0001048 1.614e-05   0.07925    0.0398  0.002381
     19/49     1.33G   0.06134   0.01422 0.0005507   0.07611        27       416   0.00204    0.1224  0.000262 3.785e-05   0.08076   0.04015   0.06863
     20/49     1.33G   0.06188   0.01432 0.0004404   0.07664        38       416  0.001445  0.007059 4.845e-05 7.261e-06   0.09249   0.04463    0.4289
     21/49     1.33G   0.05959   0.01397 0.0003659   0.07393        37       416 6.657e-05  0.002353 6.281e-07 1.256e-07      0.12    0.1272     1.764
     22/49     1.33G   0.06328   0.01439 0.0003812   0.07805        18       416 0.0005272   0.02824 1.855e-05 2.446e-06    0.1119   0.08367    0.9583
     23/49     1.33G   0.06005   0.01403 0.0003366   0.07442        51       416 0.0006283   0.03529 2.632e-05 3.142e-06   0.09945   0.04924    0.3079
     24/49     1.33G    0.0591   0.01463 0.0003125   0.07405        48       416 0.0007511   0.04471 3.902e-05 5.691e-06    0.1009    0.2225    0.5181
     25/49     1.33G   0.06012   0.01454 0.0003143   0.07497        41       416 0.0009433   0.05647 6.141e-05  8.57e-06   0.08529   0.05739    0.2311
     26/49     1.33G   0.06005   0.01409 0.0003527   0.07449        30       416  0.001691    0.1012 0.0001964 2.417e-05   0.08095   0.05117    0.1184
     27/49     1.33G    0.0615   0.01477  0.000333   0.07661        50       416 0.0004737   0.02824 1.621e-05 2.383e-06    0.1077    0.3379    0.6125
     28/49     1.33G   0.06056   0.01474 0.0004912   0.07578        33       416  0.001927    0.1153 0.0002644 3.227e-05   0.08163   0.04598    0.0535
     29/49     1.33G   0.05896   0.01474 0.0002744   0.07397        46       416  0.001509   0.08941 0.0001446 1.746e-05   0.09799    0.2672    0.4933
     30/49     1.33G   0.06094   0.01471 0.0003219   0.07597        39       416  0.002273    0.1341 0.0003333  4.72e-05   0.09563    0.1964    0.4924
     31/49     1.33G   0.06045   0.01479 0.0003004   0.07554        30       416  0.001598   0.09412 0.0001648 2.213e-05   0.09689    0.2036    0.5337
     32/49     1.33G   0.06048   0.01435  0.000284   0.07511        15       416  0.001726    0.1012  0.000185 2.502e-05   0.09312    0.2581    0.4071
     33/49     1.33G   0.05978   0.01478  0.000282   0.07484        37       416  0.002558    0.1506 0.0004851  6.25e-05   0.09286    0.3308    0.6457
     34/49     1.33G   0.05938   0.01431 0.0004091    0.0741        23       416  0.003107    0.1835 0.0007923 0.0001302    0.0965    0.6124    0.8083
     35/49     1.33G   0.06017   0.01423  0.000293   0.07469        53       416  0.001935    0.1153 0.0002564 3.823e-05   0.09742    0.3326     0.934
     36/49     1.33G    0.0613   0.01448  0.000275   0.07605        15       416  0.002259   0.05176 0.0003086 5.089e-05    0.0964    0.4585    0.8428
     37/49     1.33G   0.05863   0.01426  0.000245   0.07313        32       416  0.002012      0.12  0.000255 3.329e-05    0.1019     1.227     1.266
     38/49     1.33G     0.059   0.01524 0.0002571    0.0745        38       416  0.003543      0.08 0.0006103  8.41e-05   0.09367    0.4892    0.8013
     39/49     1.33G   0.06081   0.01433 0.0002528   0.07539        50       416  0.002254    0.1341  0.000337 5.271e-05   0.09582    0.5573    0.9453
     40/49     1.33G   0.06069    0.0146 0.0002352   0.07552        43       416  0.002669   0.05412 0.0003283 4.725e-05   0.09339    0.5353    0.9272
     41/49     1.33G   0.05904   0.01466 0.0002282   0.07393        27       416  0.001899    0.1129 0.0002256 2.807e-05    0.1054     2.773     2.208
     42/49     1.33G   0.05988   0.01498 0.0002386    0.0751        29       416  0.002208    0.1318 0.0003478 4.932e-05   0.09656     1.108     1.278
     43/49     1.33G   0.05881   0.01502 0.0002201   0.07405        10       416  0.001442   0.08471 0.0001342 1.689e-05    0.1061     1.925     3.153
     44/49     1.33G   0.05855   0.01425 0.0002135   0.07302        39       416    0.0018    0.1059 0.0003589 4.232e-05     0.103     1.673     2.153
     45/49     1.33G   0.05738   0.01485 0.0002072   0.07244         8       416  0.002748      0.12 0.0006087 7.778e-05   0.09955     1.634     1.851
     46/49     1.33G   0.05773   0.01518 0.0002102   0.07312        20       416  0.001973    0.1153 0.0002407 3.368e-05   0.09889     1.527      1.82
     47/49     1.33G   0.05676   0.01482 0.0002023   0.07178        26       416  0.002078    0.1224 0.0002903 3.782e-05   0.09504     1.559     1.507
     48/49     1.33G   0.05859   0.01522 0.0002168   0.07402        17       416  0.002492    0.1106  0.000377 5.585e-05   0.09735     2.345     1.692
     49/49     1.33G   0.05906   0.01432 0.0002073   0.07359        20       416   0.00302   0.08471 0.0005714 7.459e-05   0.09707     2.396     1.576
```

The graph of the result of the training process with no weight.
[image: --weights '']
This is the output of the training process with no weight.

```
0/49     3.77G      0.08   0.01659   0.01927    0.1159       138       416         0         0         0         0   0.09079   0.03184   0.01659
      1/49     3.79G   0.07733   0.01675   0.01569    0.1098        79       416         0         0         0         0   0.08989   0.03187   0.01262
      2/49     3.79G   0.07879   0.01635   0.01192    0.1071       129       416  0.001356   0.07059 0.0001042 1.619e-05   0.08811   0.03179  0.009986
      3/49     3.79G   0.07743   0.01605  0.009609    0.1031       156       416  0.001762    0.1012 0.0002066  2.82e-05    0.0919   0.02915  0.008755
      4/49     3.79G   0.07704   0.01638    0.0083    0.1017       170       416  0.002016    0.1129 0.0002503 3.669e-05   0.09542   0.02828   0.01041
      5/49     3.79G   0.07522   0.01563  0.006911   0.09776        68       416   0.01486  0.002353 0.0002856 3.089e-05   0.09328   0.02936  0.008026
      6/49     3.79G   0.07652    0.0164  0.006038   0.09896       149       416  0.005216  0.007059 0.0003021 4.358e-05   0.09605   0.02855   0.01244
      7/49     3.79G   0.07756   0.01629  0.005283   0.09914       115       416  0.001824  0.007059 0.0001407 2.023e-05   0.09423   0.02842  0.005517
      8/49     3.79G   0.07407   0.01571  0.004508   0.09429        75       416  0.005806  0.002353  0.000196 2.368e-05   0.09182   0.02956  0.006191
      9/49     3.79G   0.07283   0.01615  0.003928    0.0929       102       416  0.002603   0.02353 0.0002106 3.293e-05    0.1099    0.0231   0.06747
     10/49     3.79G   0.07385   0.01621  0.003418   0.09348       155       416  0.002081    0.1247 0.0002754 3.763e-05   0.09658   0.02815  0.006408
     11/49     3.79G   0.07364   0.01624  0.003138   0.09302        78       416  0.002088    0.1247 0.0002759 4.393e-05   0.09352    0.0286  0.004929
     12/49     3.79G    0.0736   0.01647  0.002794   0.09287        88       416  0.001098   0.06588  7.93e-05 9.231e-06   0.09322   0.02929  0.002459
     13/49     3.79G    0.0729    0.0163  0.002475   0.09168       147       416  0.003034      0.04 0.0004647 7.742e-05    0.1064   0.02349    0.1123
     14/49     3.79G   0.07259    0.0157  0.002354   0.09065        39       416  0.002342   0.03765 0.0002065  2.49e-05    0.1034    0.1112    0.1526
     15/49     3.79G   0.07246   0.01599  0.002065   0.09052       110       416  0.003607   0.01412 0.0003857 4.514e-05   0.09492   0.02754    0.0343
     16/49     3.79G   0.07139   0.01643  0.001893   0.08972        86       416  0.006611   0.01412 0.0001825 3.504e-05   0.09292   0.02854  0.009267
     17/49     3.79G   0.07113   0.01659  0.001945   0.08966        64       416  0.005798  0.004706 6.065e-05 9.959e-06   0.09805   0.02626   0.02191
     18/49     3.79G   0.06878   0.01623  0.001489   0.08649       116       416  0.001895   0.01412 0.0001026 1.524e-05   0.09881   0.03232   0.09805
     19/49     3.79G   0.06978   0.01624  0.001428   0.08744        79       416  0.001255   0.07529 0.0001034  1.15e-05   0.09876   0.02995    0.1162
     20/49     3.79G   0.06922   0.01672  0.001249   0.08719       120       416  0.009429  0.002353  0.000127 1.486e-05   0.09473   0.02797    0.0228
     21/49     3.79G   0.06849   0.01639  0.001146   0.08602       114       416  0.001805    0.1082 0.0002309  2.88e-05    0.0976   0.02943   0.07824
     22/49     3.79G   0.06969   0.01674  0.001075   0.08751       101       416 0.0005679   0.03294 2.162e-05 2.817e-06   0.09728   0.02738   0.03925
     23/49     3.79G   0.06868    0.0163 0.0009603   0.08594       144       416  0.002471    0.1482 0.0004183 5.975e-05   0.09078   0.03105 0.0009755
     24/49     3.79G   0.06879   0.01689  0.000945   0.08662       127       416 0.0004338   0.02588 1.391e-05 2.582e-06   0.09322   0.02698 0.0006686
     25/49     3.79G   0.06866   0.01675 0.0008683   0.08628       194       416   0.00149   0.08941 0.0001522 2.021e-05   0.09079   0.02968   0.00724
     26/49     3.79G   0.06857    0.0162  0.000918   0.08569       114       416  0.001734   0.08706 0.0001989 2.418e-05   0.09084    0.0294  0.003666
     27/49     3.79G    0.0681   0.01669 0.0007409   0.08553       130       416  0.001067   0.06353  7.39e-05 9.318e-06   0.09407   0.02832  0.003804
     28/49     3.79G   0.06787   0.01664 0.0007216   0.08524       171       416  0.004159   0.03529 0.0008557 0.0002342   0.09005   0.02947 0.0006768
     29/49     3.79G   0.06865   0.01681 0.0007021   0.08616       179       416  0.001451   0.08706 0.0001367 2.331e-05   0.09478   0.02543 0.0005066
     30/49     3.79G   0.06932   0.01627 0.0007832   0.08638       151       416         0         0         0         0     0.128     1.321     18.51
     31/49     3.79G   0.06793   0.01631 0.0006672   0.08491        97       416 0.0001715  0.007059 2.471e-06 2.769e-07    0.1286     1.402     5.569
     32/49     3.79G   0.06809   0.01603 0.0005871   0.08471       126       416  0.001824    0.1035 0.0002032 2.884e-05    0.1174    0.1189    0.7884
     33/49     3.79G    0.0672   0.01682  0.000543   0.08457       120       416         0         0         0         0    0.1273     1.725      10.7
     34/49     3.79G   0.06581   0.01632 0.0005045   0.08263        98       416  0.001536   0.09176 0.0001517 2.081e-05    0.1137    0.1111     1.181
     35/49     3.79G   0.06697    0.0162 0.0004877   0.08366       140       416  0.005047    0.1271    0.0012 0.0001472   0.09333   0.02829   0.06506
     36/49     3.79G   0.06649   0.01673 0.0004692   0.08369        94       416  0.005969    0.1106  0.001798 0.0002871   0.09215   0.02816  0.006449
     37/49     3.79G   0.06646   0.01589 0.0004647   0.08281        79       416  0.007804    0.1859   0.00253 0.0003982   0.09015   0.02921  0.002419
     38/49     3.79G   0.06704   0.01705 0.0004813   0.08458       125       416  0.006672   0.02118 0.0008473 0.0001043   0.09218   0.02866  0.002319
     39/49     3.79G   0.06733   0.01601 0.0004505    0.0838       136       416  0.006932    0.1694  0.002071 0.0003404   0.09156   0.02877  0.004387
     40/49     3.79G   0.06644   0.01641 0.0004283   0.08328       156       416  0.006756    0.2259   0.00235 0.0003657   0.09126   0.02872  0.007772
     41/49     3.79G    0.0665    0.0162 0.0004494   0.08315       119       416  0.005496    0.1694  0.001449 0.0002124   0.09321   0.02815   0.03432
     42/49     3.79G   0.06644    0.0168 0.0004249   0.08366       114       416  0.005089    0.1812  0.001463 0.0001788   0.09407   0.02861   0.04348
     43/49     3.79G   0.06634     0.017 0.0004002   0.08374        74       416  0.007598   0.07294  0.002175 0.0003309   0.09254   0.02912   0.03882
     44/49     3.79G    0.0678   0.01613 0.0004078   0.08434       148       416  0.004071   0.05647 0.0008651  0.000118    0.0922   0.02847   0.02538
     45/49     3.79G    0.0664   0.01645 0.0004711   0.08333        57       416  0.003914    0.1294 0.0008724 0.0001162   0.09208   0.02858   0.02078
     46/49     3.79G   0.06576   0.01661 0.0003853   0.08276       110       416  0.006541   0.03765  0.001291 0.0001613   0.09381   0.02794   0.03991
     47/49     3.79G   0.06625   0.01661 0.0004175   0.08328        95       416  0.005735   0.03294  0.001198 0.0001743    0.1005   0.02791     0.124
     48/49     3.79G   0.06642    0.0172 0.0003993   0.08401       120       416  0.004811    0.1082  0.001269 0.0002009   0.09766   0.04007    0.1371
     49/49     3.79G   0.06684   0.01613 0.0004152   0.08339        78       416  0.005076   0.08706  0.001382 0.0002024   0.09472   0.03317   0.05989
```

Thanks in advance. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Hi Pristina, I also using YoLoV7 and after few search and training I get to know better you try with scratch weights, yolov7_training.pt